# What's wrong with my JSON.parse and why's the code not executed in order of appearance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm importing some data with PHP, which gets data from an SQL database.  I'm using AJAX to import the data from the PHP to Javascript.  The PHP code works fine and results in "2", but something's wrong with my Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("Kategorie1.php", function (data) {
        window.nrFragen = JSON.parse(data);
        window.alert(data)
    });
    window.alert(window.nrFragen);
</script>
```

If I run it, it first runs `window.alert(window.nrFragen)` which alerts `undefined` and then `window.alert(data)`, which alerts "2", as it should.

Why does it first run the `window.alert(window.nrFragen)`, even though it's written after `window.alert(data)`?  And, why isn't `window.nrFragen = JSON.parse(data);` working?

Comment: It's because `getJSON` is an asynchronous call. It will not wait.

Comment: "import the data from the php file to a js file" - jesus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is async.

```
$.getJSON("Kategorie1.php", function (data) {
    //this will be called only after request completion
    window.nrFragen = JSON.parse(data);
    window.alert(data)
});
//this will be called immediately after $.getJSON, it won't wait for request completion
window.alert(window.nrFragen);
```

Comment: oh ok, thank you. And what can I do to let the program know to wait till the data's here?

Comment: `$.getJSON`'s second parameter is success handler which will be called when request is successfully completed. So in this callback _data's here_ already. You'd better read [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Also read some articles about asynchronous javascript (or any other language) programming like [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/).

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, I'm gona need the data for the rest of the code, so should I just let the rest of the code run after `window.nrFragen = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: yes, all your code that requires the data must be after `window.nrFragen = JSON.parse(data);`. there are other possibilities like [promises](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html)

Comment: oh, allright, thank you very much :D